# Logstash Grok pattern with double quotes

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am parsing proxy logs with Logstash and its Grok filter. The logs contain quoted strings :

```
1438120705 [.....] "SEF-EDP8" - "C"
"/GPM/1023/5745-7/456V/"
```

With the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) the following pattern works like a charm :

```
%{NUMBER:ts} [......] (-|"%{USERNAME:token1}") (-|%{DATA:token2}) (-|"%{WORD:token3}") (-|"%{DATA:token4}")
```

This does not work with Logstash's Grok because of the double quotes in the grok pattern. Logstash error log :

```
Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 9, column 204 (byte 374) after
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{NUMBER:ts} [......] ("
```

So I use the QuotedString grok pattern instead :

```
%{NUMBER:ts} [......] (-|%{QS:token1}) (-|%{DATA:token2}) (-|%{QS:token3}) (-|%{QS:token4})
```

This works with the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) as well, but quotes are extracted with quoted strings. It **doesn't work with Logstash either** :

```
token1 : ""SEF-EDP8"" token2 : null token3 : ""C"" token4 :
""/GPM/1023/5745-7/456V/""
```

How can I make it work with **Logstash**?
How can I **remove** these unwanted extra **double quotes**?

Comment: What happens if you just escape the quotes with backslashes?

Comment: Try `%{NUMBER:ts} \[[^\]]*] (-|"(%{DATA:token1})") (-|"(%{DATA:token2})") (-|"(%{DATA:token3})")( (-|"(%{DATA:token4})"))`. I have no more example input, so, not sure it will work with all of them.

Comment: @fafl it doesn't like it either

Comment: It does not need escaping, `QS` matches the quotes strings by design. You need `DATA` tokens.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew : The parenthesis does not change logstash behavior :

Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 9, column 204 (byte 374) after filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{NUMBER:ts} [......] ("

Answer (score 11):

Changing the outer double quotes to single quotes instead did the trick for me:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => 'SOME "TEXT QUOTED"' }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

If you escape " with backslash then it works fine.

%{NUMBER:ts} [......] (-|"%{USERNAME:token1}") (-|%{DATA:token2}) (-|"%{WORD:token3}") (-|"%{DATA:token4}")

Your new string will look like

%{NUMBER:ts} [......] (-|\"%{USERNAME:token1}\") (-|%{DATA:token2}) (-|\"%{WORD:token3}") (-|\"%{DATA:token4}\")

Answer (score 2):

Try gsub after you have extracted the fields with quotes

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [

      "fieldname", "\"", ""
    ]
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub